# Get the download and shared link using Onedrive (skydire) API without downloading

Tags: file, api, onedrive, picker

Please, can someone help me to show me how to modify this script just (to pick) to get the download  and shared link of a file with size and mimetype using Onedrive API without downloading the file (as in this function) :

```
    WL.init({ client_id: clientId, redirect_uri: redirectUri });

WL.login({ "scope": "wl.skydrive wl.signin" }).then(
    function(response) {
        openFromSkyDrive();
    },
    function(response) {
        log("Failed to authenticate.");
    }
);

function openFromSkyDrive() {
    WL.fileDialog({
        mode: 'open',
        select: 'single'
    }).then(
        function(response) {
            log("The following file is being downloaded:");
            log("");

            var files = response.data.files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                log(file.name);
                WL.download({ "path": file.id + "/content" });
            }
        },
        function(errorResponse) {
            log("WL.fileDialog errorResponse = " + JSON.stringify(errorResponse));
        }
    );
}

function log(message) {
    var child = document.createTextNode(message);
    var parent = document.getElementById('JsOutputDiv') || document.body;
    parent.appendChild(child);
    parent.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
```

the demo link : http://isdk.dev.live.com/dev/isdk/ISDK.aspx?category=scenarioGroup_skyDrive&index=0

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I see the following properties available for the file variable that gets returned from the picker:

id, description, name, type, link, upload_location, source, photo

via this version of the openFromSkyDrive() method:

```
function openFromSkyDrive() {
WL.fileDialog({
    mode: 'open',
    select: 'single'
}).then(
    function(response) {
        log("The following file is being downloaded:");
        log("");

        var files = response.data.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            log(file.name);

            /* show all the the properties of 'file' variable */
            for( var p in file){
                log(p);
            }

            /* get the type, which really isn't a full mimetype */
            log(file.type);

            /* get the share link */
            log(file.link);

            /* do not download the file */
           // WL.download({ "path": file.id + "/content" });
        }
    },
    function(errorResponse) {
        log("WL.fileDialog errorResponse = " + JSON.stringify(errorResponse));
    }
);
}
```